# APN Settings / Parameters

Tags: gsm, apn

while configuring  APN (Access Point Name) settings the carrier provide the APN name , APN username , APN password and also included this

APN opcode 65310

can anyone explain or have a hint to what opcode is.

Any help will be greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Operator Code](http://www.imei.info/operator-codes/) which is more commonly known as the [Mobile Country Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code)

According to the Wikipedia page on Mobile Country Code (linked above) 653 10 is the code for Swazi MTN.  653 denotes the country, 10 denotes the operator.

Comment: thanks for the hint : Another question there is this service (restful api ) been offered by a company that claims that can be accessed through a private network using gsm network. I use a GSM SIM card for my internet connectivity how can I confirm what I am actually connecting to the said private network.

Comment: The company will give you a URL to access their REST API.  You just make a GSM-network internet connection, and then access the REST API via the URL that the company has given you.  Find any sample app for consuming a REST service, and you'll see how they use the URL.  In C#, it would be HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (CompanysUrlHere))

Comment: Having been try that for days, just confirmed the GSM SIM card is registered on the correct network. Have to conclude that their restful api has been configured incorrectly.

Comment: The mobile network connection is a lower level than the HTTP connection.    Set it up and test it separately.  When the GSM connection is working, then maybe try a public REST service, like "http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=" +
                 latitude.Text +
                 "&lng=" +
                 longitude.Text +
                 "&username=demo" (replace "demo" with a username that you create on their site).  This should always work!  Then you can try the private URL.

Comment: was able to get a response from api.geonames, just can't narrow down to where the issue is with this private URL.

Comment: Try asking the company if they've got some test code that shows their interface working?